# Selector for styling in jquery plugin to a void conflicts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am new to jQuery. I recently develop a plugin bu using jQuery UI widget factory. It is working fine. I was using inline styling. But It will get complex for large files.

For the large project I have the option to use classes. But when if someone wants to use my plugin he'll simply copy the link and use it. But If he has same name of classes on his page then its page will be destroys because my of my styles. Can anyone please guide me how to avoid this.
I hope you get the point.

Thanks

Comment: You could use a "unique" prefix for your class names. Like myPlugin_Khushhal

Comment: That's why you have [namespace](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) and you can use `my-unique-plugin-****` classes (Where **** could be any class name you need)  to reduce those chances

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is this the only way to reduce these chances or any other way.

Comment: I can't tell for sure, and you didn't shown us any code so this makes it even more impossible to answer. Of course there are ways - For example, you can check the source of [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) and implement similar logic on your plugin, but again - Too broad...

Answer (score 1):

**Some things to consider:**

If you make a selector that is too specific, like

```
$("ul > li > .foo ~ .bar");
```

it may break by any changes on the markup.
However, if you don't, it will break your user's style.

As commented, the easier way to fix this would be adding an prefix on the class, like

```
<div class="my-plugin-container"> 
      <span class="my-plugin-span"> "Hello World" </span>
     (OR) <button class="my-plugin button"> </button>
</div>
```

If you could post any code we could be able to help you further. I'll edit it according when you do.

Best of luck

Comment: Thank you I think that's the solution :)